# Determine the optimal number and location of the plants and pipelines in the 7 cities.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, summation, mathematical-modeling, constraints

There are 7 cities, up to 4 plants to be made in them and up to 18 pipelines to be made connecting them.

Determine the optimal amount of plants and pipelines to be made, the optimal locations of the plants and pipelines (if any) and the optimal capacities of the plants (if any).

---

[image]

---

What I tried:

---

Variables:

Let $y_i$ be the number of plants to be constructed in city $i$.

So, $y_i = 0-4$ and $i=1-7$

Let $x_i = 1$ if no plants are constructed in city $i$ and $0$ otherwise.

Let $pc_{i1,i2}$ be the cost of constructing a pipeline from city $i1$ to city $i2$.

Let $z_{i1,i2} = 1$ if a pipeline is to be constructed from city $i1$ to city $i2$ and $0$ otherwise.

So, $z_{i,i} = 0$.

Let $pcap_{i1,i2}$ be the capacity of a pipeline that would be constructed.

Let $d_i$ be approximate discharge in city $i$. It is 5 times the population.

Let $plant_{i}$ be the combined capacities for plants that would be in city i.

---

Objective function:

Min

$$z = [1m, ..., 1.4m] \cdot [y_1, ..., y_7] + \sum_{i1}\sum_{i2} pc_{i1,i2}z_{i1,i2}$$

---

Constraints:

1. Since we want at most 4 plants,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{7} y_i \le 4$$

2. I think the combined capacities of plants in city $i$ should be greater than or equal to

approximate discharge of wastewater in that city

plus the combined capacities of the pipelines that transfer wastewater from other cities to city $i$

minus the combined capacities of the pipelines that transfer wastewater to other cities from city $i$

$$d_i + \sum_{i1=1}^{7} pcap_{i1,i} z_{i1,i} - \sum_{i1=1}^{7} pcap_{i,i1} z_{i,i1} \le plant_{i} + M(x_i)$$

3. I think cities without plants should end up with zero wastewater. Otherwise, we wouldn't need to construct any plants............I guess?

$$d_i + \sum_{i1=1}^{7} pcap_{i1,i} z_{i1,i} - \sum_{i1=1}^{7} pcap_{i,i1} z_{i,i1} = 0 + M(1-x_i)$$

4. The capacity of a pipeline from city $i1$ to $i$ should be greater than or equal to the discharge from city $i1$

$$pcap_{i1,i} \ge d_{i1}$$

---

Is that right?

Strange things:

1. I computed the combined approximate discharge of wastewater in all cities:

[image]

It turns out to be 2.25m, meanwhile the combined maximum capacities of all plants is merely 400,000. How can only 4 plants handle 2.25m of wastewater  if their maximum capacity is 400,000

2. Since the cost of constructing a plant doesn't seem to vary depending on its capacity, why not have $plant_{i} = 100,000y_i$?

---

From Chapter 3 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Answer (score 1):

Let $y_i$ be a binary that equals $1$ if and only if a plant is constructed on site $i$, and let $x_{ij}$ be another binary that equals $1$ if and only if cities $i$ and $j$ are linked by pipeline (from $i$ to $j$).

$$
\mbox{Minimize } Z= \sum_{i=1}^7c_iy_i + \sum_{i=1}^7\sum_{j\;|\;  \exists \;link(i,j)}10\frac{500}{100}p_ic_{ij}x_{ij}
$$

subject to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^7y_i\le 4\\
\sum_{i=1}^7\sum_{j=1}^7x_{ij}\le18\\
10\frac{500}{100}p_iy_i+\sum_{j\;|\;  \exists \;link(j,i)}10\frac{500}{100}p_jx_{ji}\le 100 000 +M(1-y_i)\quad \forall i=1,\cdots,7\\
1-y_i\le \sum_{j\;|\;  \exists \;link(i,j)} x_{ij}\quad \forall i=1,\cdots,7\\
x_{ij},y_i \in \{0,1\} \quad \forall i,j=1,\cdots,7
$$

**Further detail**

The first constraints limit the number of plants to 4.

The second constraints limit the number of pipelines to 18.

The third constraints are capacity constraints. You need to consider the wastewater coming from a city where a plant is built, and add the wastewater coming from neighboring cities connected to this city.

The fourth constraints impose a link between city $i$ and a city $j$ if there is no plant built in city $i$.

Comment: As usual, thanks Kuifje ^-^ 1 why does obj function need $5000p_i$? 2 why $c=\infty$ and not $0$? 3 Is the third constraint missing *1000? Or are the $p_i$'s in 1000s? 4 Does the third constraint make no distinction between a pipeline to or from city i? I was thinking to subtract the outgoing and then add the incoming. 5 re last constraint: if there is a plant in city I then there need not be any pipelines connecting to it? If there is no plant in city I , then there must be at least one pipeline connecting to it?

Comment: You're welcome! 1)  $500$ gallons/$100$ residents equals $50$ gallons/$1000$ residents, so it should be $50$ $p_i$, I have edited. 2) I was lazy with the $c_{ij}$ and have edited: only consider the existing links, its more efficient. 3) Yes the constraint was missing the same factor as in the objective function, I have edited. 4) You are right, you should only consider the incoming wastewater, I have edited. 5) Exactly: if $y_i=0$, than at least one $x_{ij}$ must be activated.

Comment: oh man, why did I have to be right. Thanks @Kuifje. I'll try to understand all that after dinner hehe

Comment: If you get other models in class for all these problems given by your professor I would be curious to have a look at them!

Comment: Oh yeah, I'll be sure to let you know if he gives a different answer (I'm going to ask in a consultation because we're not having anymore classes for our next exam).

Comment: Kuifje, 1 should $x_{ij}$ perhaps be $1$ if cities $i$ and $j$ *can be* rather than *are* linked by a pipeline (from $i$ to $j$) ? 2 Do you assume at most 1 plant per city? 3 Why is there a 10 beside the $500/100$ ? 4 Is the $| \exists link (j,i)$ just for emphasis? I think it is covered in the $x_{ji}$ variable 5 Should constraint #4 be $x_{ji}$ instead of $x_{ij}$ ?

Comment: 6 Do you use 100,000 for the reason I stated above? 7 Have you any idea how to account for the 2.25m and the 400,000?